WordPress editor mobile view crashes, says: Error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node
I am using the latest version of WordPress (6.5.2) and regardless of which theme I am using or if I turn the plugins all off, whenever I try to enter the tab or mobile responsive view on the page editor it crashes and gives the following error message:
Error: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
I have tried reinstalling WP, changing themes and changing plugins, but am not having any luck at all.  Nor have I been able to find a solution. It appears to be a problem with the WP core file: react-dom.min.js, but I am hesitant to mess with it.
Here's what the console says when it crashes:
react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10 DOMException: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': The node to be removed is not a child of this node.
at $r (...p.temp-site.link/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:75182)
at jr (...p.temp-site.link/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:74867)
at $r (...p.temp-site.link/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:75624)
at jr (...p.temp-site.link/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:74867)
at $r (...p.temp-site.link/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:75948)
at Kr (...p.temp-site.link/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:76434)
at Yr (...p.temp-site.link/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:78007)
at Kr (...p.temp-site.link/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:76584)
at Yr (...p.temp-site.link/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:76896)
at Kr (...p.temp-site.link/wp-includes/js/dist/vendor/react-dom.min.js?ver=18.2.0:10:76584)

Note: I removed the first part of the url in the links above.*

I am currently hosting this dev site on my own VPS server using RunCloud. I have many other WordPress sites on it that are working just fine, but this one, and two others that I am currently building on it are having this same problem.
Does anyone out there happen to have a quick fix for this?
Many thanks in advance!

Also, in case this is helpful, when I tried using a Media cleaner plugin, that same error popped up.
https://snipboard.io/JwEBP6.jpg
